# Append XML String to Element in Java

Tags: java, dom

I have a requirement in which I need to append a XML String to Element in Java. Below code shows what I am doing now:

```
Document doc;
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = builder.newDocument();
Element results = doc.createElement("Results");
doc.appendChild(results);
Element row = doc.createElement("Row");
results.appendChild(row);
String columnName = "XML_00805F49916B";
String valueString = "<IBS><Product></Product></IBS>";
Element node = doc.createElement(columnName);
node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(valueString));
row.appendChild(node);

DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(sw);
transformer.transform(domSource, sr);
retMsg = sw.toString();
System.out.println("SQL Return message: " + retMsg);
```

The above code returns output:

```
SQL Return message: <Results><Row><XML_00805F49916B>&lt;IBS&gt;&lt;Product&gt;&lt;/Product&gt;&lt;/IBS&gt;</XML_00805F49916B></Row></Results>
```

But, I want the output to be:

```
SQL Return message: <Results><Row><XML_00805F49916B><IBS><Product></Product></IBS></XML_00805F49916B></Row></Results>
```

Please can I have some help how to get the required output?

Comment: You have to add the nodes via the DOM API not as a string. You use a text node, so the special characters are escaped.

Comment: Can I have some reference or example of how to use the DOM API for my case?

Comment: You already have three calls to `doc.createElement`, so I assume you know how to use it.  You will need two more, one for an `IBS` element and one for its `Product` child element.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting that XML i.e. valueString from external source, and its schema would be different all times. I need a generic way of adding a XML string value into Element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A text node is not part of an XML document’s structure.  It’s just text.  The special characters `<`, `>`, and `&` are just characters when it comes to text nodes, though the final XML representation will need to escape them.

You cannot accomplish your goal by inserting a text node.  You need to insert elements.

From your comment:

> Unfortunately I am getting that XML i.e. valueString from external source, and its schema would be different all times. I need a generic way of adding a XML string value into Element

You can parse arbitrary XML content into a new XML document, and then [import](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode(org.w3c.dom.Node,boolean)) (copy) the new document’s root element to your document:

```
String columnName = "XML_00805F49916B";
String valueString = "<IBS><Product></Product></IBS>";
Element node = doc.createElement(columnName);

Document valueDoc = builder.parse(
    new InputSource(new StringReader(valueString)));
Node valueElement = doc.importNode(valueDoc.getDocumentElement(), true);
node.appendChild(valueElement);

row.appendChild(node);
```